# How does one implement a dexterity.membrane user and group?

Tags: plone, dexterity

On Plone 4.3.7, as per `Products.Membrane` & `dexterity.membrane` instructions, I've added a CustomMember & CustomGroup content type and assigned them the proper behaviors. After adding instances of them, going to membrane_tool, adding those types (seems this was required) to the selection of membrane content and reindexing, instances of custom member types show up in membrane_tool catalog.

However, groups do not show up (in membrane_tool catalog). Neither do the groups show up in the regular site management Users/Groups  UI, but I guess that's to be expected (given they are not catalogued).

Neither can I log in using the credentials entered when adding CustomMember instances.

What additional steps are there to make custom Dexterity-based Users & Groups work? Is the group assignment done by containment (ie. a CustomUser must be added inside a `CustomGroup`) or via some other mechanism? And how are roles assigned?

P.S. I've also tried out the example member content type provided by `dexterity.membrane`, but trying to add that results in an [error](https://github.com/collective/dexterity.membrane/issues/16).

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation expects the membrane user to have a "enabled" workdflow state.